# add data to an arrayList, when If condition is satisfied in nested for loop in Kotlin

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, arraylist, hashmap, nested-loops

Check the code below:

```
 getCommonsArrayList(listA:ArrayList< User >, listB:ArrayList<User>):ArrayList<User>{

    var listCommon = ArrayList<User>()

    for (i in listA.indices) { 
        for (j in listB.indices) {
            if (listA[i].id.equals(listB[j].id)) { //if id of the user matches
                listCommon.put(listA[i]) //add to a new list 
            }
        }
    }

    return listCommon // return the new list with common entries
}
```

The above method iterates list a & b and check whether the id's are matching, if they are then the User object is stored to a new list and at the end of the program, it returns the common list.
**This thing works good.** *And I hope nested for followed by if condition is the way in which we can compare two lists.*

The problem with this is if **listA** has repeated entries, then the **listCommon** will also have repeated entries as ArrayList supports duplicacy of entries.

So what I did to make commonList unique is I introduced a HashMap object as shown below:

```
  getCommonsArrayList(listA:ArrayList< User >, listB:ArrayList<User>):ArrayList<User>{

            var listCommon = ArrayList<User>()

            var arrResponseMap = HashMap<String,User>()


            for (i in listA.indices) { 
                for (j in listB.indices) {
                    if (listA[i].id.equals(listB[j].id)) { //if id of the user matches
                     arrResponseMap.put(listA[i].id,listA[i]) // add id to map so there would be no duplicacy
                    }
                }

             }
      arrResponseMap.forEach {
            listCommon.add(it.value) //iterate the map and add all values 
        }

            return listCommon // return the new list with common entries
   }
```

This will give the new arrayList of userObject with common Id's. But this has an increased complexity than the above code.

If the size of the **listA** and **listB** increases to *1000* then this execution will take heavy time.

Can someone guide me if there is some better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `distinctBy` to get only unique values from list.

[Official Doc:](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/distinct-by.html)

> Returns a sequence containing only elements from the given sequence
>   having distinct keys returned by the given selector function.
>
> The elements in the resulting sequence are in the same order as they
>   were in the source sequence.

Here is an example:

```
        val model1 = UserModel()
        model1.userId = 1
        val model2 = UserModel()
        model1.userId = 2
        val model3 = UserModel()
        model1.userId = 1
        val model4 = UserModel()
        model1.userId = 2

        val commonList = listOf(model1, model2, model3, model4)
        // get unique list based on userID, use any field to base your distinction
        val uniqueList = commonList
            .distinctBy { it.userId }
            .toList()

        assert(uniqueList.count() == 2)
        assert(commonList.count() == 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the both the list and use distinctBy like this

```
 data class DevelopersDetail(val domain: String, val role: String)
    val d1 = DevelopersDetail("a", "1")
    val d2 = DevelopersDetail("b", "1")
    val d3 = DevelopersDetail("c", "1")
    val d4 = DevelopersDetail("c", "1")
    val d5 = DevelopersDetail("d", "1")

    var listA = listOf(d1, d2, d3, d4)
    var listb = listOf(d1, d2, d3, d4)


    var data = listA + listb
    var list= data
        .distinctBy { it.domain }
        .toList()

    println("list   $list")

   //output-list   [DevelopersDetail(domain=a, role=1), DevelopersDetail(domain=b, role=1), DevelopersDetail(domain=c, role=1)]
```